# jquery ajax on page load and subsequent ajax call after 5 mins crashes browser after a while

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to execute an ajax call on page load then subsequently every 5 mins. This seems to work at first but overtime it seems ajax is called heaps of times at once which ends up crashing my browser. When I check the browser development console (network tab) i can see heaps of requests sent at once and increases each time.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    function sendRequest(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "data.php",
            success: function(data){    
                //do stuff with data..
            },
            complete: function() {
                setInterval(sendRequest, 300000); // Call AJAX every 5 mins (in milliseconds)
            }
        });
    };

    sendRequest();

});
```

Is there anything wrong with the above code snippet or way to improve it to ensure only one ajax is called after 5 mins.

Just to reiterate what I am trying to do:

1. Call ajax on-page load
2. Call ajax every 5 mins afterwards

Comment: Use `setTimeout()`, not `setInterval()`. Your current logic is creating a new interval every 5 minutes so the number of requests you send grows exponentially.

Comment: simply replacing setInterval with setTimeout seemed to work. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calling `setInterval` on every ajax call complete which is in result setting interval call of `sendRequest` method multiple time and causing issue.

call `setInterval` just once outside the ajax call which will call `sendRequest` method for every 5 min, see below code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    function sendRequest(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "data.php",
            success: function(data){    
                //do stuff with data..
            },
            complete: function() {
            }
        });
    };
    sendRequest();
    setInterval(sendRequest, 300000); // Call AJAX every 5 mins (in milliseconds)
});
```